# How can I display world time in javascript using php time() as a base time?

Tags: javascript, php

How can I display time of different countries using javascript?
I'm trying to use PHP (America/New_York) to get a baseTime, pass it to javascript and then display different time for respective countries.

```
<?php
print '
<script type="text/javascript">
var baseTime = "'. time(). '";

//javascript functions
function australiaTime(){

// what do I do here to convert baseTime into australia time?

}//function

function usaTime(){  }

function IndiaTime(){ }

function hongkongTime(){  }

function londonTime(){  }

function japanTime(){ }



</script>
';
?>
```

I was looking at some world time examples, but they all use client side PC time to do whatever they are doing. What if PC clock is not correctly set?
What can I do here?

Comment: Have you searched any answers on the internet first? Maybe you should now try to reinvent the wheel, but check for other examples. Surely someone have tried this before, since it sounds really common.
Could check this out to see if it is what you want
http://www.proglogic.com/code/javascript/time/worldclock.php

Comment: You could just skip the php tag around the script, and then just have the script and do var baseTime = '<?=time()?>'

Comment: You do have to get the time and timezone from a certain place. Using PHP you could get your server's time, provided that it is indeed correct(being a server, it's time should be updated)

Comment: if you have already found some examples, why not pass the php time into them instead of the Client side pc time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use library **momentjs**: http://momentjs.com/timezone/

example :

```
var newYork    = moment.tz("<?=date("Y-m-d h:i") ?>", "America/New_York");
var losAngeles = newYork.clone().tz("America/Los_Angeles");
var london     = newYork.clone().tz("Europe/London");

newYork.format();    // 2014-06-01T12:00:00-04:00
losAngeles.format(); // 2014-06-01T09:00:00-07:00
london.format();     // 2014-06-01T17:00:00+01:00
```